# Square: Is there a way to keep text in Description that does not get rendered at the store?

Tags: ember.js, square-connect

Is there a way to store a piece of text (8 to 12 chars) in Description or elsewhere that does not get rendered for the online store?  Outside Description is OK, as long as this piece of text is accessible through ITEM_READ API (Get Items). I tried to wrap this text with HTML comments and that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach two arbitrary strings (called `sku` and `user_data`) to [Item Variations](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/#datatype-itemvariation) - they will show up in the API but not in the description. It's probably better to use the `user_data` field for your purpose. You should be aware, however, that this field is not scoped per-application, so if you have multiple API client applications using this field for different purposes they will interfere with each other.

EDIT: If you want this to be merchant-visible in the merchant's dashboard, it looks like your only option would be to use the SKU, which is meant for unique item identifiers (e.g. UPC or ISBN). The SKU is visible in this little box.
[image]

Comment: @ Troy - thank you - I could not locate a way to access this in the UI/Square Dashboard - "Item Library".  My intention is to let the merchant enter data in the UI, this data is available to the  Square App AND this data is not rendered for the online store. (sorry - I did not clearly state the need that the merchant has to enter it)

Comment: Looks like the SKU is your only option; I updated my answer.